# How to upload data to firebase database using reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I had previously tried using django for this project but switched to reactjs but encountering some similar problems. The data isn't being uploaded to real time database or to storage. The page doesn't navigate with the navigate function placed after the firebase upload

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "firebase/compat/database";
import "firebase/compat/storage";

  const AddRestaurant = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [city, setCity] = useState("");
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [website, setWebsite] = useState("");
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  //const [url, setUrl] = useState("");

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const imageRef = storageRef.child(`images/${image.name}.jpg`);
    await imageRef.put(image);
    const imageUrl = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();

    firebase.database().ref("Restaurant").push({
      name,
      city,
      location,
      phone,
      website,
      imageUrl,
    });
    navigate("/restaurants");
    
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="center">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          className="border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-md p-2 w-full"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="center">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="City"
          value={city}
          onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
          className="border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-md p-2 w-full"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="center">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Location"
          value={location}
          onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
          className="border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-md p-2 w-full"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="center">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Phone"
          value={phone}
          onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}
          className="border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-md p-2 w-full"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="center">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Website"
          value={website}
          onChange={(e) => setWebsite(e.target.value)}
          className="border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-md p-2 w-full"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="center">
        <input type="file" onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])} />
      </div>
      <div className="center">
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-md p-2 w-full"
        >
          Add Restaurant
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default AddRestaurant;
```

I placed the navigate function after the handlesubmit is initiated and it navigated to the next page but no save in the db. Also I would like to add functionality to update restaurant details by name after reading said name from db. Is it wiser to use firestore for this?

Answer (score 0):

Writing to the database (and pretty any call to a cloud API) is an asynchronous operation, as it may take some time to complete. But before that write operation completes, your code already navigates to the next page.

To solve this, wait for the database write to complete, and only then navigate to the next page:

```
await firebase.database().ref("Restaurant").push({
  name,
  city,
  location,
  phone,
  website,
  imageUrl,
});
navigate("/restaurants");
```